# yii - use of class for CGridView's column shows php warning

Tags: php, yii, error-handling, cgridview, zii-widgets

I need to apply a CSS class to one CGridView's column and I'm getting a PHP notice error

This is the code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'),
            'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider( getArray() ),
            'template'=>"{items}",
            'columns'=>array(
                array('name'=>'title', 'header'=>'Title', 'cssClassExpression'=>'span3'),
                array('name'=>'url', 'header'=>'url'),
            ),
        ));
```

And this is the notice i get:

```
PHP notice
Use of undefined constant span3 - assumed 'span3'
```

If i disable PHP notices i correctly see the css class applied to my column.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: You have somewhere unquoted `span3` string

Comment: unfortunately not, I have checked the whole file and I only had that occurrence. I think I have found a solution, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem using a different syntax for the CGridView column:

```
array('name'=>'title', 'header'=>'Title', 'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span3')),
```

Answer (score 0):

For completness...

This error comes from fact, that `cssClassExpression` value must be [php callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) or if it's string it is `eval`'uated, according to source of `evaluateExpression`:

```
    if(is_string($_expression_))
    {
        extract($_data_);
        return eval('return '.$_expression_.';');
    }
    else
    {
        $_data_[]=$this;
        return call_user_func_array($_expression_, $_data_);
    }
```

This might be used to conditionally set css class. For simple setting of css class, use `htmlOptions`, as Marco has found, and posted in answer.